# ansible apache edit directory definitions

Tags: apache, ansible

What I have is:
testje.conf:

```
#
<Directory "/some">
    bla bla
    bla
    bla
    AllowOverride option1 option2 ...
    bla
</Directory>
<Directory "/where">
    bla
    AllowOverrideList option
    bla
    bla
</Directory>
<Directory "/else">
    bla
    bla
</Directory>
```

What I want is to ensure that every directory has "AllowOverride None". So replace AllowOverrideList to AllowOverride None and also add the AllowOverride in the directory where it is missing.

test.yml:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - replace:
      path: testje.conf
      regexp: '(<Directory.*)(AllowOverride[A-Za-z ]*)(.*<\/Directory>)'
      replace: '\g<1>AllowOverride None\g<3>'
      backup: yes
```

and you guessed it right, I am not a regex wonder ....

```
ansible-playbook testje.yml -i "localhost," -c local
```

how/what should I change make this task work as requested? Can it be done in one task or should I add a separate task to add the missing line?

wanted output:

```
#
<Directory "/some">
    bla bla
    bla
    bla
    AllowOverride None
    bla
</Directory>
<Directory "/where">
    bla
    AllowOverride None
    bla
    bla
</Directory>
<Directory "/else">
    bla
    bla
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination of following two tasks can get the expected output:

```
- replace:
    dest: testje.conf
    regexp: '^    AllowOverride.*$'
    replace: '    AllowOverride None'
    backup: yes

- replace:
    dest: testje.conf
    regexp: '(<Directory.*\n)((    (?!AllowOverride).*\n)*)(</Directory>.*\n)'
    replace: '\1\2    AllowOverride None\n\4'
    backup: yes
```

Comment: thanks, at first I was trying to edit only between the tags but this works fine since in the end adding of a missing directive is added only between the tags.